# Relation between Resonant frequency and Resistance in series RLC circuit

Tags: capacitor, frequency, passive-networks, resonance, coupling

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdoyVB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have a series RLC circuit and I calculated the resonance frequency. Say its w (omega).

Now in second experiment, i use the resistor of half the value used in above ciruit. What effect will it have on my resonant frequency now?

Example:

Experiment 1: C = 100nF, L = 100mH, R = 100ohms

Experiment 2: C = 100nF, L = 100mH, R = 50ohms

Only resistor is changed. Nothing else.

Comment: Please also draw a schematic with the tool.

Comment: I just added the diagram.

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/serres.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What effect will it have on my resonant frequency

Theoretically it will have no effect on the resonant frequency. The resonant frequency is purely determined by the capacitor having exactly the opposite reactance of the inductor at *a* particular frequency and the two reactances cancel leaving the series tuned circuit having only resistance at resonance.

However, with lower values of resistance the peak shape of the resonance will change but the centre point of the peak will remain as previous.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Andy. Can you specify any formula or a relation relating to this?

Comment: I think you know the resonant frequency formula from what you say in your question. I've added a pretty picture to confirm this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can I say that since the equation: Omega=1/(underroot of LC) has no resistance therefore omega is not dependent on R?

Comment: Yes you can but this is only true of some RLC resonant circuits and this happens to be one of them.

Comment: Okay this helps a lot, thanks for your help Andy! Cheers!!